# Minecraft testforblock command problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help specifying a command! Right now I have the following command:

```
/testforblock -565 18 -1357 chest 3 {Items:[{id:sapling}]}
```

How can I specify the sapling to a dark oak sapling? Also once it found the sapling how can I remove only 1 sapling from the chest?

Answer (score 1):

Saplings use the `Damage` tag to store their type. Dark Oak's value is 5 and `Damage` is a `short` type, hence the `s`.

This command should test for a *dark oak* sapling in the chest.

```
/testforblock -565 18 -1357 chest 3 {Items:[{id:"sapling", Damage:5s}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I remove 1 item like the sapling from a chest?

Comment: Unless you want to make 64 commands for every different amount of f items you can have in a stack, you can only remove stacks at a time. You could use the `Count` tag to get/set the amount, but no easy way to decrease the item count by 1.